# How to auto save the output from network device using MobaXterm?

Tags: mobaxterm

How can we auto save the output from network device using MobaXterm?

I tried to use the save logs, but it saves just the localhost logs, I need to save every new session output I opened.

Comment: This has been asked a few times at least in Stack Overflow. Here's one of the threads: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422135/mobaxterm-log-all-new-terminal-activity-in-a-separate-file

Comment: Good catch Peregrino69. And welcome SU sir Sudqui Al-Imam